# Projection of intersection of half-spaces is closed

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, convex-analysis

Suppose $P\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is an intersection of closed half-spaces. So there exist $v_1,...,v_k\in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that

$$P= \{x\in \mathbb{R}^n:\langle x, v_i\rangle \geq 0~ \text{for} ~ i =1,...,k\} $$

Let $\pi: \mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$ be the standard projection to the first $m$ coordinates. What is the easiest way to see that $\pi(P)$ is a closed set?

I though maybe $\pi$ might respect finite intersections of half spaces, but it clearly doesn't (take $n=2, m=1$, $P=\{y\geq x\}\cap \{y\leq -x\}$) . Another idea might be to project down one dimension at a time, provided that it can be shown that the image of the projection to $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ is again an intersection of half-spaces.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to convert $P$ to the form
$$
P = \{ A x \mid x \in \mathbb R^m, \; x \ge 0 \}
$$
for some matrix $A \in \mathbb R^{n \times m}$.